# Ruby libs for Twitter User/Site streams?

Tags: ruby, twitter, stream

Are there any ruby libs to handle twitter user / site streams?

Answer (score 2):

the twitter-stream gem can do that.
http://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-stream

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/scootklein

currently has user streams, working on site streams (very much beta, and planning on integrating back into the parent fork)